# Formatted column button doesn't start the flow

Tags: permissions, flow, json-formatting, check-permissions

I am having an issue, that none of the members of my organization can call a flow from a formatted column button in a Sharepoint list.

Below is the script used to create this button:

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/declarative-customization/column-formatting#create-a-button-to-launch-a-flow

Below is a screenshot of how this button is on my list, and works pretty fine for my user account.

[image]

When a team member clicks on the same button (using his account), the flow window comes up, but doesn't show anything:

[image]

This is how I have granted permission to this team member runs this flow. Initially I have added him as a Run only member, also it didn't work. Then I changed to Owner member, even though the issue is still there:

[image]

Does anyone have any light of what could be the issue?

Comment: Still couldn't find the culprit for the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We found that the issues was caused by the browser.

Used Edge and it worked fine.